# What's wrong in my reasoning about this deduction?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

In my text book when I was studying stochastic process, It was presented to my an example about stochastic process, a "oscillator sinusoidal with random phase":
$$x(t) = A\cdot sin(2\pi f_0 t + \theta)   $$

where $\theta$ is  a random variable with uniform distribution from $[- \pi,\pi]$ in other words:
$$ p_\theta(\Theta) = \frac{1}{2\pi} \space for [-\pi,\pi]$$

the objective here is discover the correspondent density probability of x(t), so second my mind, I need use this property:

$$p_{x_t}(X) =\frac{ p_\theta(\Theta)}{|g{'}(\theta)|}\Big|_{\theta = g^{-1}(x_t)}  \ $$

second my reasoning:
$$
|g{'}(\theta)|\Big|_{\theta = g^{-1}(x_t)}  \ = (sin^{-1}(x_t) - 2\pi f_0t){'}\Big|_{\theta = g^{-1}(x_t)}  \ = \frac{1}{\sqrt{A^{2}-x^{2}}}
$$

and finally:

$$
p_{x_t}(X) =\begin{cases} \displaystyle
   \frac{1}{2\pi\sqrt{A^{2}-x^{2}}} \space\space 
 for \space\space|x| \leq A\\
  0 \space\space\space\space 
 for \space\space |x| > A
\end{cases}
$$

however, in my text, the result is this:
$$
p_{x_t}(X) =\begin{cases} \displaystyle
   \frac{1}{\pi\sqrt{A^{2}-x^{2}}} \space\space 
 for \space\space|x| \leq A\\
  0 \space\space\space\space 
 for \space\space |x| > A
\end{cases}
$$
What did I do wrong? I review my calculus a lot of times, and it looks right but I know that is something wrong because the integration from $-\infty$ to $\infty$ is not 1 in the case of my answer, in the case of text book's answer this property is satisfied.

Comment: $\theta \mapsto A \sin(2\pi f_0t +\theta)$ is not a $C^1$-diffeomorphism on $(-\pi,\pi)$ so you can't (directly) apply the change of variable formula.

Comment: I've tried to do exactly you said, but the answer is more different, first I applied the derivative : $$ g{'}(\theta) = A\cdot cos(2\pi f_0 t + \theta) $$             
 thiking about trigonometric properties I found out that $$sin^{-1}(\frac{x_t}{A}) =\frac{\pi}{2}-cos^{-1}(\frac{x_t}{A})$$as$$sin(k)=cos\left(\theta-\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$$and$$cos(k)=cos(-k)=cos\left(k-\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$$then$$\\ g{-1}(x_t)=Acos\left(-\left(-\frac{\pi}{2}+cos^{-1}(\frac{x_t}{A})\right)\right)=Acos(\frac{x_t}{A}-\frac{\pi}{2})=Acos(cos^{-1}(x_t))\\|g{'}(g^{-1}(x_t))|=x_t\\p_{x_t}(x_t)=\frac{1}{2\pi x_t} $$